# Dragino LoRa v1.3 data sheet and proper pin configurations

Tags: lora

I am a student, currently doing my internship and working on arduino mega2560 and Dragino LoRa shield v1.3. I was searching the data sheet for Dragino LoRa shield v1.3 on the internet, but I have been unsuccessful to find any. I have Sx1276 chip data sheet (http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/sx1276.pdf)used in Dragino LoRa shield v1.3 board. But there is no proper data sheet for the entire board. Can anyone help? I want to understand the pin configurations and pin mapping. There is another resource I found on GitHub, however, it is quite hard to understand (https://github.com/dragino/Lora/tree/master/Lora%20Shield/hardware/v1.3). Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see pretty much anything you want.

https://github.com/dragino/Lora/blob/master/Lora%20Shield/hardware/v1.3/Lora%20Shield%20v1.3.sch.pdf

You have to understand: The Square in the top left is your board. You can see every connected Pin has its name for example pin 14 is CLK. You can search for the CLK on the RFM95 and you will see it is pin 4.

Hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding relationship between sx1278 chip data sheet and the sheild board is showed in the scheme.
In fact,you just need to know the sheild pin is connected in the default way when it is inserted directly in the mega 2560，but the ss pin （DIO 10 of the sheild board ）maybe should be connected with DIO53 of mega 2560,you can try it.The default way you can refer to  its introduction on Wikipedia.